# Xamarin.Android display dropdown menu when Home Button on ActionBar is clicked

Tags: android, android-actionbar, xamarin

I need to display a dropdown menu showing logout option when the Home button on actionbar is clicked.So i overided this method

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected (IMenuItem item)
        {

            if (item.ItemId == Android.Resource.Id.Home) {
                OpenOptionsMenu (); 
            // StartActivity (typeof(MainActivity));
            }
            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected (item);
        }
```

But the debugger prints optionmenu is empty.How can i populate the optionmenu with data items?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in `OpenOptionsMenu()`? Display a prompt to logout? Or put items in the `ActionBar`?

Comment: @kevskree i need to show the dropdown menu with a single item 'LogOut' when the user clicks on the Home Icon.Basically the menu should come under the home icon.